# How to break a Linestring in n parts in PostGis

Tags: postgis

I have a Linestring shapefile, one of the columns of the table has a number inside (2, 6, 7, etc), I need to break the linestring into equal segments based on that field. For example:

If the linestring has a 6 in that field, I need it to break in 6 equal segments, if the number is 10, in ten segments and so on.

I tried ST_Subdivide, ST_Segmentize, ST_Linesubstring but I can't manage to reach that, I get to break the line based on specific distance but I don't want that.

Comment: Packed as a set of PL/PgSQL functions [here](https://github.com/geozelot/postgis-addons/blob/master/SQL/st_linesubstringsbyvalue.sql), readme [here](https://github.com/geozelot/postgis-addons/blob/master/SQL/README.md#setof-geometry_dump-st_linesubstringsbylengthgeom-geometrylinestring-seg_len-float8). C function addon [here](https://github.com/geozelot/postgis-addons/tree/master/C) (needs rebuild).

Comment: Coudn't manage to work, the functions created correctly but the results where not correct, probalby my mistake, but I think I did it right. Thanks for the help anyways

Comment: Uff, apparently, for whatever reason, I edited out some important part a while ago :-D They work now as expected.

Comment: Will check it out, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve this, you would need to call `st_lineSubstring` several times, one for each desired part.

We need the start and end percentage of the substring. We can get these values by dividing the "part" number by the total number of parts in the linestring (the `n` input).

We compute this automatically generating each part number using `generate_series` between 0 (the 1st part) and `n-1`. To get these part numbers for each input, the trick is to do a `cross join lateral` (for each row of the source table, generate a series from 0 to `n`, `n` being read from the source table row).

The 2nd trick is to specify a step of 1.0 in generate_series, allowing to get decimals when we compute the percentage.

```sql
WITH src(id,n,geom) AS (values 
    (1,4,'linestring(0 0, 10 10)'),
    (2,3, 'linestring(1 3, 1 9)'),
    (3,10, 'linestring(100 100, 100 110)'))
SELECT id,part,n, st_asText(geom) as src_geom, 
  round(part/n,2) as from_pc, round((part+1)/n,2) as to_pc,
  st_asText(ST_LineSubstring(geom, part/n, (part+1)/n)) as part_geom
FROM src
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(0,n-1,1.0) AS part;

 id | part | n  |          src_geom           | from_pc | to_pc |          part_geom
----+------+----+-----------------------------+---------+-------+-----------------------------
  1 |    0 |  4 | LINESTRING(0 0,10 10)       |    0.00 |  0.25 | LINESTRING(0 0,2.5 2.5)
  1 |  1.0 |  4 | LINESTRING(0 0,10 10)       |    0.25 |  0.50 | LINESTRING(2.5 2.5,5 5)
  1 |  2.0 |  4 | LINESTRING(0 0,10 10)       |    0.50 |  0.75 | LINESTRING(5 5,7.5 7.5)
  1 |  3.0 |  4 | LINESTRING(0 0,10 10)       |    0.75 |  1.00 | LINESTRING(7.5 7.5,10 10)
  2 |    0 |  3 | LINESTRING(1 3,1 9)         |    0.00 |  0.33 | LINESTRING(1 3,1 5)
  2 |  1.0 |  3 | LINESTRING(1 3,1 9)         |    0.33 |  0.67 | LINESTRING(1 5,1 7)
  2 |  2.0 |  3 | LINESTRING(1 3,1 9)         |    0.67 |  1.00 | LINESTRING(1 7,1 9)
  3 |    0 | 10 | LINESTRING(100 100,100 110) |    0.00 |  0.10 | LINESTRING(100 100,100 101)
  3 |  1.0 | 10 | LINESTRING(100 100,100 110) |    0.10 |  0.20 | LINESTRING(100 101,100 102)
  3 |  2.0 | 10 | LINESTRING(100 100,100 110) |    0.20 |  0.30 | LINESTRING(100 102,100 103)
  3 |  3.0 | 10 | LINESTRING(100 100,100 110) |    0.30 |  0.40 | LINESTRING(100 103,100 104)
  3 |  4.0 | 10 | LINESTRING(100 100,100 110) |    0.40 |  0.50 | LINESTRING(100 104,100 105)
  3 |  5.0 | 10 | LINESTRING(100 100,100 110) |    0.50 |  0.60 | LINESTRING(100 105,100 106)
  3 |  6.0 | 10 | LINESTRING(100 100,100 110) |    0.60 |  0.70 | LINESTRING(100 106,100 107)
  3 |  7.0 | 10 | LINESTRING(100 100,100 110) |    0.70 |  0.80 | LINESTRING(100 107,100 108)
  3 |  8.0 | 10 | LINESTRING(100 100,100 110) |    0.80 |  0.90 | LINESTRING(100 108,100 109)
  3 |  9.0 | 10 | LINESTRING(100 100,100 110) |    0.90 |  1.00 | LINESTRING(100 109,100 110)
```

Comment: Works wonderful, big thanks. If you have time, could you please explain a little bit more the logic behind that? I get some of it but not at all, I'm a little new to PostGis.